# Add color to the track bar of control - slider based in react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using the [control-slider](https://jaywilz.github.io/react-bootstrap-range-slider/) component based in react-bootstrap:

[image]

My question is how can add styles in react to put a color to the track bar,I want look like this:

[image]